# Alternative expressions for n factorial over n-k factorial

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I have the following question that I am struggling to figure out.

For positive integers, ${n}$, ${k}$ with $n > k$, which of the following also expresses $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

A. ${n^k}$

B. ${n(n-1)...(n-k)}$

C. ${n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}$

D. ${n^{n-k}}$

When I test $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ with ${n = 5}$ and ${k = 2}$ I get a result of 20. However, none of the options have the same result when using the same numbers. If $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ can be expressed by one of the options shouldn't they calculations provide the same result if using the same numbers for ${n = 5}$ and ${k = 2}$? Thank you.

Computations:

A. ${n^k}$ => ${5^2 = 25}$

B. ${n(n-1)...(n-k)}$ => ${5(4)(3) = 60}$

C. ${n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}$ => ${5(4)(4) = 80}$

D. ${n^{n-k}}$ => ${5^3 = 125}$

Comment: Can you show us how you compute what you got for A, B, C and D when $n=5$ and $k=2$? I do get $20$ for one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Christoph. I edited my post with my calculations. Am I doing the arithmetic wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$ as "multiply the numbers counting down from $n$ to $(n-k+1)$", it does not necessarily have three or more factors.

When $n=5$ and $k=2$ you get $5\cdot 4=20$.